# Receiving a 405 Method Not Allowed using Web API on POST request. How do I fix this?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

My action method has the following signature in the controller class:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/fun")]
public class FunController : ApiController
{

  [HttpPost]
  [Route("domagic")]
  public HttpResponseMessage PerformMagic(string email)
  {
      ...
  }
}
```

When I post to it with PostMan in Chrome or the iOS client I'm writing, I get 405 Method Not Allowed. I post to /api/fun/domagic. Changing the request type to GET, gives me an error that essentially tells me that Web API is mapping to a different method.

In my WebApiConfig, I call `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();`. In my Web.config, I remove all system.webServer/handlers, then add the following handler. (This is all boilerplate default stuff after File-> New Project)

```
<add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```

I added the following to system.webServer/modules:

```
<remove name="WebDAVModule"/>
```

From all my searching, this setup should work, but it doesn't. POST always fails.

What do I need to do to make it work?

Comment: If you have the option, I'd try uninstalling webdav from IIS entirely - I've had persistent problems with this as well, and seen SE discussions that suggest disabling webdav isn't always enough.